# openGLES 2.0 - Cocos2d, showing white where alpha is reduced

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, alpha

Ok, hey guys. This is the first time I've had to ask a question myself, since I can't seem to find what I'm looking for anywhere.

I'm using Cocos2D and CCDrawingPrimitives to draw points with a fade.
It was working perfectly. Now, instead of going transparent, the points just get more and more white. I didn't change anything in the code either so it's annoying. Anyway I'm seeing the same issue within other areas of my app as well. When I want transparency I get a blend of the original colour over pure white.
I've tried alot of different blend combinations etc.

I have kind of fixed the problem by fading the brightness of the colour as I lower the alpha. but it was much better before since on anything other than white the reducing brightness is a bit noticeable...

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: do you run glClearColor anywhere or did you change a blendFunc property?

Comment: fixed it, thanks for that. I had changed the blend. Making sure to change it back to gl_src_alpha, gl_one_minus_src_alpha seems to have fixed it perfectly.

Cheers!